# Beginner C# applications

Tags: c#

I just started learning C#, and I want to start making some small applications that are easy, but powerful.

Does anyone have any projects ideas? I'm interested to hear what you have in mind. Most of my experience is with HTML, CSS, JS, PHP.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think there is anything more powerful than getting your first "Hello World" to work in a new language you have never done before.

Comment: Yes, and after the 10 seconds that will take I would imagine he may want to move onto something more challenging.

Comment: I agree with Scott that "Hello World" is a great first. If you have done a fair amount of programming in other languages, though, this often feels too trivial. Tic Tac Toe is one of my favorite seconds.

Comment: 99 bottles on the wall is better: introduces looping and conditionals. Or if you're feeling brave, recursion :-)

Comment: what skills do you want to learn? Basic control flow, data-structures, OO design? How 'beginner' do you want things?

Comment: Please note that [you should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page. To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where every answer is equally valid: "What's your favorite ____?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 3):

Since C# can be used in multiple types of applications, I'd try to do the same task in each.  Perhaps a simple app that connects to a database and performs a lookup based on user input.  Maybe connect to the "pubs" database that comes with the SQL Server samples.

You could do this as:

- Winforms
- ASP.NET WebForms
- ASP.NET MVC
- Dynamic Data
- WPF
- A Console app

using

- Standard ADO.NET
- LINQ
- Entity Framework

You can even create a Windows Service that uses WCF, and a WinForms or ASP.NET front-end that consumes that service.

The idea is to get as many TYPES of apps under your belt as possible, so you can see how each is similar, and how each is the same.  It will also help you get a better understanding of the "religious wars" over "which is best, Web Forms vs. MVC", etc.  The ultimate answers to those "holy war" questions is invariably "what you're most comfortable with".  There's nothing like having actual experience with the various options than to actually write something, so a nice, simple app in all of the available flavors would be a very good start.

And finally, since I listed so many things, here are some great starting points for everything I mentioned.  There are videos, walk-throughs, etc to help you on your way.

http://www.asp.net/

http://windowsclient.net/default.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/beginner/default.aspx

Comment: Why bother with ADO.NET? Shouldn't one go straight to LINQ and/or WCF?

Comment: @Qwertie - I can think of several reasons. 1. because under the hood, even LINQ is dependent on ADO.NET. Therefore, understanding ADO.NET helps greatly in troubleshooting. 2. It's more "similar" to accessing data in other languages. The concept of creating a connection, creating a command, executing a command, getting results back, etc are concepts that most devs coming from other languages should be able to relate to. 3. There are situations where it's simpler to just use standard ADO.NET without the overhead of the generated LINQ to SQL classes, etc.

Answer (score 3):

What do you like doing? I find **games** are always a cool place to start. If you like game-development you can do stuff like pong and pacman, but you can still have a lot of fun just making board and card games without much of the graphics complexity.

Here's some to get you started:

easier: tic-tac-toe, connect-4, go fish, black-jack, candyland, various solitaire games

medium: monopoly, poker, go, checkers, Yahtzee,

harder: scrabble, boggle, chess, Magic: The Gathering

---

here's different levels of difficulty:

1. design the logic. For example, make classes and methods to represent the board, properties, and the players in monopoly.
2. start making a gui. Make the game actually playable!
3. add AI and computer controlled players. Obviously AI is a huge subject, so there's many different ways you can go.

---

### **[see here for a ton more projects on various topics](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/78802-martyr2s-mega-project-ideas-list/)**

Answer (score 1):

How about a scientific calculator? It'll give you basic experience with GUI building and event handling, it shouldn't be too hard to knock one up and most of your focus will be on the language rather than complicated algorithms (which is what you want when you're just starting to pick up a language.)

Answer (score 1):

I've always heard that a simple game like checkers is good place to start. It lets you handle things like:

- Separation of Model from UI (possibly
  with a view model).
- Skinning of controls or custom controls

and is easy to understand and test.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create something likes todo list. You can to provide a lot of custom feature for it (save/open data files, import to other formats, UI)

Answer (score 1):

A good place to start is something like a calendar/todo application.

You won't beat all the great programs already out there that solve this problem, but you can start with a very simple but functional program, and add a feature a day for the rest of your life without running out of things you can do.

This gives a lot of opportunities for using different UI elements, doing some custom graphics rendering, serialisation/streams/io, database access, and even synchronising with web-based calendars, etc. i.e. It's easy to find a use for many different .net technologies within an application like this, but you don't *need* to use them: you can write a basic "useful" application in only a few minutes and keep adding to its facilities to learn new technologies.

Answer (score 1):

Write a graphical dice roller simulator. It should be one window and when I press the "Roll Dice" button it simulates a roll of the dice, showing me an image of how my dice landed. And bonus points if it makes a nice dice roll sound. Extra bonus points if you let me choose how many dice to roll.

I expect to see this by tomorrow afternoon.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, something I'd like right now is a program that performs batch file management operations...

- Sorting files into subfolders based on date or name patterns;
- Renaming files based on user-defined patterns (e.g. add or remove a prefix from all filenames)
- Renaming files based on metadata, if you can figure out how to read it (e.g. mp3 ID3 tags)

Then again, maybe this is too advanced. Or boring. I always find it fun to write a game that is a clone of an existing game, but add a twist. Like 3D tic-tac-toe... bad example maybe, but you get the idea.

Comment: Actually file operations is something that I think would be best saved for later unless you know most of your work will be doing that. File operations are more a feature of the framework than the language.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a little more advanced, but I enjoyed creating a little cheating program for playing the bejeweled blitz game. I followed Mike Vallotton's blog to get me started. it's [here](http://mikevallotton.wordpress.com/2009/08/19/i-cheat-at-bejeweled-blitz/)

Answer (score 0):

Another good one would be to count the number of words in a text file.

Add a little more functionality to it by searching for keywords and returning how many of those were found in the text.

Comment: What kind of application would you make for this? A console app, WPF  or windows form app?

Comment: I would start with a console app since they are the most simple.

Comment: I actually developed that app today.

Answer (score 0):

Start with writing a simple program using Form Application using a button and when clicked: Open a MessageBox saying Hello World. Then going over to new stuff like a webbrowser and then obtaining the source code from the site
3 basic steps in learning c# by webbrowser development:
1. create a basic browser that opens up a hardcoded site (site preprogrammed, not decided by user)
2. user controlled, textbox that the user can decide webpage with.
3.pulling out source code and changing every picture on a page for example. That will combine HTML and C# and since you have experience with HTML, changing the client side of the WebPage is good practice.

Good Luck :) Look up ThenewBoston on youtube, really great tutorials on C#

Answer (score 0):

got a couple ideas:

- you can make a pretty basic **calculator** [console application or windows form application]
- you can make a **dice** (give random number between 1-6 **or** a random number between two numbers selected by the user.
- a **magic 8 ball**, this uses the dice in the previous dot point, but instead uses the randomised integer and prints out the corresponding string.
- you can make a **planner** application (an app that saves data such as todo list on a .txt file, etc).
- you can also make a **desktop assistant** (i made one recently), that recognises voice and speaks to the user. It can also obey simple commands.
- if you want to go deeper, you can try coding using C# to create **unity games**, i had some experience in this, it is very easy (got pretty good at it after reading some documentation and watching some tutorials).

but if you are **just** starting out, then i recommend you to work your way upwards and start off with making something simple.